# Replacing half of the content of a bottle with salt

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, random

Imagine that we have $s_0$ grams of sugar in a bottle. Then we randomly extract half of the content of the Bottle and replace it with salt.

Let $s_n$ be the grams of sugar inside the bottle after we repeat this $n$ times.

> My question is: If we keep doing this, will the number of grams of sugar tend to $0$? This is: is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} s_n = 0$?

What if instead of replacing half of the content with salt we replace $k\%$ of it, for any $0 < k < 100$?

What is the expected number of grams after we do this $n$ times?

Comment: Do you replace half of the volume or half of the mass?

Comment: Isn't it the same? @MichaelHoppe

Comment: Not at all: one cubic centimetre sugar has a mass of 1.59 grams whereas the mass of one cubic centimetre salt is 2.16 grams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem misses an important precision : how many grains of sugar/salt ? or some precision about the mixing.
If you suppose the number of grains of salt/sugar to be infinite and the mixing to be perfect, then this is no more a probabilistic problem.

$S_n = \frac{s_0}{2^n}$ so its limit is 0.

and with $k$ : $S_n = s_0.k^n$

Comment: After we add the salt we shake the bottle, that will randomise the mixing, so the mixing can be perfect in some areas but not in others, the mixing is random